# addeventlistener function argument is null on one webpage, but functions properly on others

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-devtools, web-frontend

I'm doing the frontend on my clients website and have come across a strange issue. On certain pages (maybe 5% of the total pages on the site), the simple hamburger icon javascript doesn't function at all.

Here is the JS (which, again, works on 95% of the pages):

```
const userBox = document.querySelector(".wdgt-user-box");
const userBtn = document.querySelector(".wdgt-login");

function toggleUserBox() {
    if (userBox.style.display === "block") {
        userBox.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        userBox.style.display = "block";
    }
}
userBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleUserBox);
```

Some things to rule out:

- Z-index is not an issue. I *can* click on the icon (I tried adding an href and it worked).
- The HTML and JS (and how the JS is linked) is exactly the same on all pages. The JS is included at the bottom of the HTML in all cases
- The queryselector appears to be working in all cases when inspecting with Chrome dev tools

The one difference I noticed when setting up breakpoints is that when hovering over "toggleUserBox" on the pages where it doesn't work, Arguments: null. Here is the difference between the two:

[image: Pages where it doesn't work]
[image: Pages where it DOES work]

Of course, please let me know if there is more useful info I can find. I'm new to Chrome dev tools.

Comment: Some other code, somewhere, is calling the function not as an event handler. Where? I don't know. Look for the function name in your source code; from what you posted, nobody can tell.

Comment: @Pointy This is really helpful, will start looking. Thank you

Comment: @Pointy The function is not being called anywhere else. Is there anything else I can look into that may be interfering?

Comment: A function registered as an event listener and called due to a browser event will **always** be passed a parameter. You might try adding `console.log(new Error)` to the function so that you can see a stack trace when it's called.

Comment: Also, the information you posted looks like (in the second case) it's from a point *during a call* to the event handler. The first one looks like it is *not* during a call to the function: it's not just the `arguments` list, it's also `callee` etc.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you again for this info, you're right about your second point. Unfortunately, I cannot even get console.log() to work on click. Also, of course, no errors appear in the console. Is there a place where I can see what could be stopping *any* JS from working on specific pages? Or is this not something dev tools can help me with?

Comment: There's not really a general solution to this. Personally I always want to be able to "see" into the code, so adding `console.log()` to track what's going on (and later taking them out, of course) is pretty much all you can do.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using a class as the query selector, you could try checking if there is more than one object with the same class name on the page

Comment: The query selectors seem to working properly